# Change icon in "Activity Drawer"

Tags: android, layout, icons, drawerlayout, drawer

i'm a trying to learn how to build Android Application, so i'm playing with Android Studio. I have selected from Android Studio a new Drawer activity but i want to use an "Home Icon" instead of camer icon for example but the resource "ic_menu_home" included in sdk is private i'm trying to use my personal home icon downloaded from google developer site but when i run my app my personal icon isn't displayed. Here is the code of the file "activity_nameofactivity_drawer":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" //my personal icon
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/places_ic_search"
        android:title="Search" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>
<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

but this is my drawer: [drawer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEIzD.png)

someone can help me ?

Comment: Can you please send a link to where you got the icon from?

Comment: did you save `ic_home_black_24dp` in the "res/drawable" folder?

Comment: @AkashBhave here: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_home

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio:

1. In the left-hand Project window, right click on the `res` folder and select New > **Image Asset**
2. On **Asset type** choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons**
3. Choose the **image path**
4. Give your image a name in Resource name
5. Select `Finish`

You might find the [Resources Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) and the [Drawable Resources Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said and it half works becouse now i can see my new icon but it is smaller than other icons, i tried to resize it but nothing changed. Some tips ?

Comment: When you go through that process it should automatically provide you with different densities - hdmi, mdpi, etc. - If you just have one drawable, try removing it first and trying again. If that doesn't help, try manually generating the files in photoshop/GIMP and dragging/dropping. I'll add the docs for `Resources` you can check out too.

Comment: Ok thanks. I declared the image asset as launcher and the home button has the real dimension. I don't know why but now it works, so...good. Thanks anyways :)